# Dependently typed printf in Idris

Tags: idris

I am trying to translate to Idris an example from the *Cayenne - a language with dependent types* [paper](http://fsl.cs.uiuc.edu/images/5/5e/Cayenne.pdf).

Here is what I have so far:

```
PrintfType : (List Char) -> Type
PrintfType Nil                = String
PrintfType ('%' :: 'd' :: cs) = Int -> PrintfType cs
PrintfType ('%' :: 's' :: cs) = String -> PrintfType cs
PrintfType ('%' ::  _  :: cs) = PrintfType cs
PrintfType ( _  :: cs)        = PrintfType cs

printf : (fmt: List Char) -> PrintfType fmt
printf fmt = rec fmt "" where
  rec : (f: List Char) -> String -> PrintfType f
  rec Nil acc = acc
  rec ('%' :: 'd' :: cs) acc = \i => rec cs (acc ++ (show i))
  rec ('%' :: 's' :: cs) acc = \s => rec cs (acc ++ s) 
  rec ('%' ::  _  :: cs) acc = rec cs acc  -- this is line 49
  rec ( c  :: cs)        acc = rec cs (acc ++ (pack [c]))
```

I am using `List Char` instead of `String` for the *format* argument in order to facilitate with pattern matching as I quickly ran into complexity with pattern matching on `String`.

Unfortunately I get an error message I am not able to make sense of:

```
Type checking ./sprintf.idr
sprintf.idr:49:Can't unify PrintfType (Prelude.List.:: '%' (Prelude.List.:: t cs)) with PrintfType cs

Specifically:
    Can't convert PrintfType (Prelude.List.:: '%' (Prelude.List.:: t cs)) with PrintfType cs
```

If I comment out all the pattern match cases with 3 elements (the ones with `'%' :: ...`) in `PrintfType` and `printf`, then the code compiles (but obviously doesn't do anything interesting).

How do I fix my code so that `printf "the %s is %d" "answer" 42` works?

Answer (score 15):

It looks like there are some [current limitations](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/idris-lang/jIUnwuldZhc/m2ki5A_9hS0J) in idris when defining functions where the patterns overlap (for instance `'%' :: 'd'` overlaps with `c :: cs`. After many tries, I finally figured out a workaround for this:

```
data Format = End | FInt Format | FString Format | FChar Char Format
fromList : List Char -> Format
fromList Nil                = End
fromList ('%' :: 'd' :: cs) = FInt    (fromList cs)
fromList ('%' :: 's' :: cs) = FString (fromList cs)
fromList (c :: cs)          = FChar c (fromList cs)

PrintfType : Format -> Type
PrintfType End            = String
PrintfType (FInt rest)    = Int -> PrintfType rest
PrintfType (FString rest) = String -> PrintfType rest
PrintfType (FChar c rest) = PrintfType rest

printf : (fmt: String) -> PrintfType (fromList $ unpack fmt)
printf fmt = printFormat (fromList $ unpack fmt) where
  printFormat : (fmt: Format) -> PrintfType fmt
  printFormat fmt = rec fmt "" where
    rec : (f: Format) -> String -> PrintfType f
    rec End acc            = acc
    rec (FInt rest) acc    = \i: Int => rec rest (acc ++ (show i))
    rec (FString rest) acc = \s: String => rec rest (acc ++ s)
    rec (FChar c rest) acc = rec rest (acc ++ (pack [c]))
```

`Format` is a recursive data type representing the format string. `FInt` is a int placeholder, `FString` is a string placeholder and `FChar` is a char literal. Using `Format` I can defined the `PrintfType` and implement `printFormat`. From there, I can smoothly extend to take a string rather than a `List Char` or a `Format` value. And the end result is:

```
*sprintf> printf "the %s is %d" "answer" 42
"the answer is 42" : String
```

Comment: What kind of proof do you need to provide to make this `printf` work with a runtime string?

Comment: @is7s, good question, I don't know. I haven't played with Idris since this question/answer. I can see some idea in http://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/drafts/eff-tutorial.pdf where it says _return a proof that the integer is in the required range along with the integer itself_. So I guess you would have to parse the format string and return it with a proof that is has some `Format`.